# Ubuntu Studio 22.04.2 installed (full), want to switch from KDE Plasma desktop. What are my options?

Tags: gnome, kde, desktop-environments, plasma, ubuntu-studio

1 partition on 500gb ssd. I'd prefer Gnome or even XFCE but I suppose I'd have to use an older version of U.Studio. Can I install a desktop UI w/out installing a complete OS? Or must I reinstall a plain Ubuntu (Gnome) version and DL individual Studio packages, and the low-latency kernel which is key, and probably a tough install?

Comment: Ubuntu Studio has an installer which works with all Ubuntu *flavors* (see https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-installer/) so there is no need at downloading *individual Studio packages* you mention for Ubuntu Desktop, or any Ubuntu *flavor*. It's not a difficult install; being QA-tested for all *flavors* too. If it was me, I'd just add another desktop, but sorry I'm not an audio person & have limited experience with Ubuntu Studio (*and that's mainly testing installs!*), despite me having much experience switching desktops on installs (*alas without Ubuntu Studio components added*)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out: the Installer appears to make the low-latency kernel and other facets of Studio a seamless install. Based on the responses so far I'm going to have to reinstall a different flavor of Ubuntu and add Studio capabilities via this Installer. Letting KDE take up space on the SSD is pointless.

Comment: My opinion is No you don't...  The box I'm using now is Ubuntu Desktop (ie. GNOME); though installation media I used was Lubuntu's ISO thus I also have the Lubuntu/LXQt desktop, I've added Xubuntu/Xfce to it, plus of course Ubuntu's Desktop (GNOME) too.. ie. our systems can have more than a single DE installed.. however I don't create audio/video anything thus don't include Ubuntu Studio code on my used systems. I interact with Ubuntu Studio *devs* but mostly with regard installer (`calamares`) & *shared* code. I'd backup first, then try adding second desktop... you can also start clean later

Comment: @guiverc I thank you for your clarification, it was starting to dawn on me that yes it was done, but I went ahead and reinstalled, as I would never have a reason to go back to KDE. However I may experiment with Xubuntu in time. And yes the Ubuntu Studio Installer worked a treat. Still loading stuff from there, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can install the desktop without a lot of packages by this command:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Thanks @talaat that may work for me but as I'm going to do a full reinstall I may as well get full functionality. For a side-install it would be ideal; I just don't want KDE on my system.

Comment: @realself `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: I went ahead and full-installed Ubuntu, as I will never use KDE. But thanks anyway, it's good to know those options. I will research "no-install-recommends" DE.